# Real numbers as infinte product of primes

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

We can uniquely write every number in $\mathbb{Q}_+$ as $\prod_{i=1}^{N} p_i^{n_i}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number and $\{ n_i \}_{i=1}^{N}$ is some finite sequence of indices, with each $n_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. You can then use these sequences to represent the rational numbers. You can perform operations on such sequences as discussed here http://rjwagner49.com/Mathematics/PrimeVector/. This made me wonder if we could do something similar for the real numbers, that is:

Can we uniquely write every number in the form $\mathbb{R}_+$ as $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{k_i}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number and  $\{k_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is some infinite sequence of indices in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that the infinite product converges? Thus, the set $\mathbb{R}_+$ would then be equivalent to the set of all such sequences. (Note that we require the product to converge in $\mathbb{R}_+$, or else we obtain multiple representations of $0$).

I at first doubted that such a statement could hold, but I couldn't come up with any sort of counter example or contradiction.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, the infinite series will diverge. You probably know this, but another extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ where primes are involved is the [p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: Sounds like you are feeling around Cantor's theorem

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597555/product-of-all-primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...such that the infinite product converges...

The only integer sequences $(k_i)$ such that the infinite product $\prod\limits_ip_i^{k_i}$ converges to some nonzero limit are such that $k_i=0$ for every $i$ large enough (otherwise the partial products jump infinitely often from some value $s$ to some value greater than $2s$ or smaller than $\frac12s$, which, unless $s\to0$, implies divergence).

Hence the numbers which can be written as such infinite products are exactly the nonnegative rational numbers.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning here. However, why do we say the product diverges when it is identical to the product $\prod_{i} p_{2i}^{k_{2i}}p_{2i+1}^{k_{2i+1}}$. This product should be able to converge under the standard definition, right? As we can choose $k_{2i}$ and $k_{2i+1}$ such that each term of the series is arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Because the definition of the product $\prod\limits_kQ_k$ being convergent is that $\prod\limits_{k\leqslant n}Q_k$ converges when $n\to\infty$, not that $\prod\limits_{k\leqslant 2n}Q_k$ does.

Answer (score 2):

The infinite product cannot converge to any positive number unless eventually every term is $1$, that is, only finitely many of the $k_i$ are non-zero. The reason is that for any $k_i\neq 0$, when going from the $(i-1)$th to the $i$th partial product, you're either multiplying by or dividing by some power of the $i$th prime, which will eventually be a very large number.